# mysql: splitting over tables or rows

Tags: mysql, oop, database-design

I am new to the DB world, but i do have a decent knowledge or ER and EER diagrams from University.

my problem is that i have no idea how to expand/modify my DB.

lets start with the current structure:

```
-Clients
--id
--first name
--last name 
--dob
--registration
--TherapistID (Foreign key)
--...

-Therapists
--id
--first name
--last name 
--dob
--registration
--licenseID (Foreign key)
--...

Licenses
--id
--max reg keys possible

-Reg keys
--id
--LicenceID (Foreign key)
--Mac address
```

2 distractions arise:

- redundant structure (common columns) in therapist and client
- having a dedicated table for licenses

my bane(or blessing) here is that i come from java and OOP:

my solution for 1st point: extract common data between therapist and client -> put them in users table -> link therapist and client to users by foreign key.

my friend's solution for 1st point: merge both therapist and client into one table (user) with flags (which i remember my professor might kill someone over it because it creates to many nulls) -> any extra data relevant to therapists, for example, is added in other tables with foreign keys to it (all hail joins).

my solution for 2nd point is to just leave it. it's easier to add more columns to  it when i need to.

what do you guys and gals think is better, and since i am a total nub, any unnoticed nuances pointed at (e.g. naming convention) are encouraged

Comment: Are you saying that each client can have only one therapist?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes. sorry about the late reply. i was sick.

Comment: @PM77-1 , 1 therapist to n clients. 1 license to n registration keys. 1 license to 1 therapist.